# Collection.find() only works on certain Collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I have set up a MongoDB with Express and Mongoose to communicate with my Angular App.

I'm currently experiencing the following problem:

There are 3 different Collections so far. When I try to go for `Collection.find({})` on 2 of them it works perfectly fine, but when I try to get the entries of the 3rd one I always just get an empty Array ( "[]" NEVER undefined or something always just empty braces).

When I try to fetch the entries in the MongoDB shell cli it works perfectly fine with the exact same command.

So here is my non-working code (the specification is not the problem ({name: 1, _id: 0}), I also tried in a lot of different ways without it):

```
app.get('/api/retrieveCompany', async (req, res) => {
    Company.find({},{name: 1, _id: 0}, function(err, companies) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json('Error')
        } else {
            console.log(companies)
            res.status(200).json(companies)
        }
    })
})
```

Code of the method that is **working just fine**:

```
app.get('/api/retrieveContent', async (req, res) => {
    Content.find({}, function(err, contents) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json('Error')
        } else {
            console.log(contents)
            res.status(200).json(contents)
        }
    })
})
```

Rest of code that is used for that method:

Mongoose Schema (Company):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    boss: String,
})

const Company = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema)

module.exports = Company
```

Initiation:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/angulardb', { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then((err) => console.log('Mongoose up'))

const User = require('./models/users')
const Content = require('./models/content')
const Company = require('./models/company')
```

Mongoose Schema (Content) (**only for comparison**):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const ContentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    subject: String,
    customer: String,
    task: String,
    date: Date,
    inCharge: String,
    comment: [String],
})

const Content = mongoose.model('Content', ContentSchema)

module.exports = Content
```

Response I get from the MongoDB Shell CLI:

```
> db.company.find({},{name: 1, _id: 0})
{ "name" : "IT Solutions" }
{ "name" : "Microsoft" }
{ "name" : "Company15" }
{ "name" : "New Company" }
```

Comment: The "company" collection is where happens the empty result?

Comment: Yes. Not empty result, but an array without any content.

Comment: Have you tried to find all your companies without a projection?

Comment: Yes i did, but no possible alternative (at least from what I know) did work. Not even just going for Company.find({}, function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mongoose documentation,

> Mongoose by default produces a collection name by passing the model
>   name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the
>   name. Set this option if you need a different name for your
>   collection.

But I saw your collection name is in singular form. You can rename your collection or use this to use different collection name.

```
const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    boss: String,
}, { collection: 'company' })
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: wow that is unfortunate, i tried companies, companys, Companies and Companys because i thought I'd need to name the thing in plural... I feel dumb af now :D Thank you for helping that fast.

Comment: Glad to help you. :)